# How to align several objects on the same x coordianate?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

I have several objects with different x coordinates.
If I select them all and transform them to a x coordinate Illustrator sets the x coordinates relative to the selection as a whole.
I want to set the x coordinate for all objects the same.

So: The objects should be in line below each other, starting at the same x.
Is there any way to do it? I don't want to set the x coordinate for the objects separatly.

Comment: Have you tried using the Align Tool `Shift + F7`?

Comment: have you tried the align tools? https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/moving-aligning-distributing-objects.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the *Align* tool **Window** → **Align** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)
and select **Horizontal Align**.

---

[image]

Make sure you select what you are trying to align it to.

- **Artboard** - Align it all with the center of the artboard
- **Selection** - Average it out in the middle (all will still be perfectly aligned)
- **Key Object** - Align it to the selection which has the Bold outline (you can change the key object by just clicking on a different object)

Comment: So, this is helpful and works, but seems a little bit like a workaround if I get it right. In case of objects that are a little bit too far on the left and some are a little bit too far on the right, I would need several steps instead of just typing in the x coordinate, right?

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas You can place one object in the exact spot you want them all to be in, and align to `Key Object`