# Why objects are not distributing in between first and last object in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have seen in the internet that by selecting several objects, clicking on `Horizontal Distribute Center` or `Horizontal Distribute Space` will result in distributing the objects with same space in between first and last selected objects. But in my case, the objects are distributing throughout the artboard width, not in between first and last selected object. Please see the attached image for example.

[image]

How to distribute object only in between first and last selected objects?

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/91059/63979

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `Align to` option to **Selection**.

[image]

Select your rectangles, then use the **Distribute Spacing** option to equally distribute the space between each object.

Comment: Although I fixed it myself but Yes...the underlying cause was that Align option actually. Mine was set to Key Object....While I changed that, all things went well.